# Prevent Visual Studio from crashing (sometimes)

Tags: visual-studio

How can I stop Visual Studio (both 2005 and 2008) from crashing (sometimes) when I select the "Close All But This" option?This does not happen all the time either.

Answer (score 1):

First, check [Windows Update](http://www.windowsupdate.com) and make sure both VS environments are up to date.

If that doesn't help, uninstall them both completely, reinstall only 2005, update and test it. If 2005 doesn't crash, install 2008, update and test them both. Don't install any add-ons you may have been using until you've reinstalled and tested both editions of VS.

If one or the other does crash, you should try [filing a bug against Visual Studio](http://blogs.msdn.com/astebner/articles/451329.aspx).

If they didn't crash, install any add-ons that you use one at a time and continue to test both editions after each one. (This will take ages, but that's how it has to be) When they start crashing, remove the offending add-on, and file a bug with the add-on developer. (be sure to tell them what other add-ons you're using, in case it only happens when 2 conflicting add-ons are installed.)

Answer (score 0):

I would highly consider uninstalling and then installing Visual Studio again. Afterwards make sure you have installed available service packs for your VS version.

Answer (score 0):

- Does it happen on all projects or a specific one?
- Does it only occurs when a specific file is open?
- Try re-installing visual studio and any/all service packs.

Answer (score 0):

Try to reset the Visual Studio settings (**Tools->Import and Export Settings->Reset All Settings**).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try to reproduce this using a specific solution and csproject file and report it to Microsoft?

That's the best shot you can ever have.

Answer (score -1):

Another alternative:

1. Study for 10 years to become a really good programmer
2. Apply for (and get) a job at Microsoft in the Visual Studio team
3. Fix the bug